# ARM template - depending on resources from the outside of resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

Here's what I have on Azure:

```
Resource group: 'microservice-1'
App Service: 'app-service-1'
Database: 'database-1'

Resource group: 'microservice-2'
App Service: 'app-service-2'
Database: 'database-2'

Resource group: 'shared-infrastructure'
Database: 'shared-database-1'
```

Both microservices use `shared-database-1`. Every microservice contain ARM template script to create/update resource group that is used when microservice is deployed. In ARM scripts we can define dependencies (dependsOn) so that the resources are updated with proper order but this work only within resource group.

Here's the scenario I want to run:
There's nothing in Azure and I want to release `microservice-1`. Is there a
mechanism in Azure / ARM that I can use, so that `shared-infrastructure`
release (ARM template) is run prior to `microservice-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you specifically include that in your ARM Template. DependOn just check if the resource is there, it won't magically create it for you.

But you could include that in your template and if it exists, it won't do anything, unless you specify deploymentmode = complete.

So you could create 3 templates,: for microservice-1, microservice-2 and for shared-infrastructure. In your templates for microservices you could include the deployment to create shared infrastructure and it won't do it if its already in place

**Edited based on comments:**

You can link resources in the same subscription after deployment. There's no way to do that with ARM, but PowerShell + ARM could do that, you could search for existing instances of shared resource and if its not there - create it with an ARM template and after that invoke another ARM template to deploy the actual service.

Comment: The question is "how to include it". I know linked templates, but this can be used only within the same resource group.

Comment: you can link resources in the same subscription after deployment https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-link-resources/. but that won't help you solve your problem, there's no way to do what you are doing, yet.

Comment: The way to ensure this then would be to run multiple deployments each time - as mentioned that will just "make it so", so if it exists, it's a no-op, if it doesn't it will create it.  Deployment mode won't matter in this case, unless you have extra resources in the group that are not in the template - if you do "Complete" mode will remove them, but will behave the same as incremental for existing resources.

Comment: thanks Brian, actually, when I think about it, there's no way to do that with ARM, but PowerShell + ARM could do that, you could search for existing instances of shared resource and if its not there - create it with an ARM template and after that invoke another ARM template to deploy the actual service